# ModuleNotFoundError seen when running test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a project directory as below:

```
bin/
bin/module1/module1.py
bin/module1/settings.py 
bin/module1/helpers.py  --> This module does not have reference to bin/module1/settings.py
bin/module2/module2.py
bin/module2/settings.py
bin/module2/helpers.py --> This module has reference to bin/module2/settings.py
bin/tests/test_module1.py --> This test imports helpers from bin/module1/helpers.py
bin/tests/test_module2.py --> This test imports helpers from bin/module2/helpers.py
bin/tox.ini
bin/conftest.py
bin/setup.py
```

setup.py has below contents:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_project',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Implement my_project',
    long_description='Implement my_project',
    author='my_name',
    author_email='a.my_name@my_domain.com',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*'])
)
```

I am using pytest.

When I run `test_module1.py`, which refers `bin/module1/helpers.py` using pytest markers and `bin/module1/helpers.py` does not have import to  `bin/module1/settings.py`. The test run perfectly fine.

But, when I run `bin/tests/test_module2.py` using pytest markers, and `bin/module2/helpers.py` has import to `bin/module2/settings.py`, when this test runs I see the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings' error`

```
    import settings as settings
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

Answer (score 0):

The only method i know is to change
`import settings as settings`
to
`import .settings as settings`
Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, but `import .settings as settings` throws error. So, I changed to `from .settings import *` it worked. This works fine when running as test i.e. `bin/tests/test_module2.py`

But, when I run python module `bin/module2/module2.py` I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved using SO link: [Getting "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" when running from Python Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088071/getting-importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package-wh)

Used Approach 1 from above link which is as below:

```
try:
    # Assume we're a sub-module in a package.
    from . import models
except ImportError:
    # Apparently no higher-level package has been imported, fall back to a local import.
    import models
```